# How to know if a list of coordinates forms a rectangle?

Tags: python, list, matrix, coordinates

I am currently trying to figure out how to check if my list, for instance this :

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

forms a rectangle like this :

```
A B
C D
```

with A, B, C and D respectivly [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0] and [1, 1] of the list.
The idea is of course to do something generic, so something like :

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0]]

==> X X X X
    X
```

should return false.

Is there any mathematic concept that I can use ? Or maybe I ask this question the wrong way, and there is an obvious way that I can't see ! Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Maybe this is a better question for mathematics stackexchange...?

Comment: I thought about it. But as I said, maybe there is a simple solution that doens't require any """" advanced """" math concepts.

Comment: There has to be one solution where `[a c] [a d] [b c] [b d]` holds true. If you sort them prior to the comparison, it should be trivial to see whether the points meet that criteria.

Comment: Start with some basic ideas. If the number of coordinates is odd, then they'll be a straggler somewhere, i.e. it won't be rectangular. Then check for pairs, if not every coordinate is in a pair, then there will be a straggler, and it won't be rectangular. Stuff like that

Comment: Also look at this question for ideas http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176938/how-to-check-if-4-points-form-a-square

Comment: @Zzul yeah, but the question isn't really a *programming* question. I'm sure the math-heads over there don't mind helping a programmer if you ask an on-topic question. Anyway, I'm sure this is likely to get an answer here, but I do feel it is a better fit for another SE site.

Comment: @TemporalWolf and af3ld : if I understand well, i have to check if any number a, b, c.. exists an even number of time in an even sized list. As my case, i'll never a size greater than 6, and each coordinates come right after the previous one. I can never have something like : `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [5, 9]]`

Comment: Is it possible to check if each array element occurs **exactly twice** in the same position in the main list? (I tried but my Python-fu lacks the necessary list comprehension strength.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several properties you can harness to get this done.

First, of course, is that a rectangle has exactly four vertices; your second list should be rejected on those grounds alone.  :-)

Otherwise, you can check the slopes of the sides.  A parallelogram has opposite sides parallel.  The slope of a line segment from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) is

```
m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
```

Once you verify that you have a parallelogram, you need to check that the adjacent sides are perpendicular.  Such lines have slopes whose product is -1.  So if you've computed the four slopes m1 through m4, and verified m1=m3 and m2=m4, all that's left is to check any one corner:

```
if m1*m2 = -1:
    ...
```

Note that your equality checks here shouldn't require an *exact* match; float rounding can give you tiny differences.  Instead, perhaps

```
if abs(m1*m2 + 1) < 0.000001:
```

---

Another property that might give you a more direct result is that a figure is a rectangle if and only if the diagonals bisect each other.  Take your two diagonals and find the midpoints.

```
xmid = (x1 + x2)/2
ymid = (y1 + y2)/2
```

If the two midpoints are the same (or very close), then you have a rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

If they have to be inline with the coordinate plane:

```
def isRect(coords):
    if len(coords) != 4:
        return False
    tA, tB, tC, tD = sorted(coords)
    return tA[0] == tB[0] and tC[0] == tD[0] and tA[1] == tC[1] and tB[1] == tD[1]
```

which is enforcing `[a c] [a d] [b c] [b d]` by sorting them by `x`, then `y`, then doing a boolean comparison.

Comment: could you not do `key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0])`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga your order is backwards, but yes, that works as well. I've updated my answer.

Comment: uh, in which case you don't even need a key-function, no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga also correct, as the default sort is sufficient.

Comment: A very bad, but accurate, idea: `def isRect(coords): return [False, sorted(coords)[0][0] == sorted(coords)[1][0] and sorted(coords)[2][0] == sorted(coords)[3][0] and sorted(coords)[0][1] == sorted(coords)[2][1] and sorted(coords)[1][1] == sorted(coords)[3][1]][len(coords) == 4]` as a single line.

Comment: I'm sure someone would call it "pythonic"

Answer (score 0):

A different solution you can try is incorporating the orthogonality of the rectangles line segments. If you import the math module or numpy module, you can check to see if each consecutive pair of line segments forms a right angle. You can extend this idea into properties of diagonals, or can use the diagonals to find out if the corner angles are right angles. You can also amend the code and apply the distance formula; if the lengths of each line in the rectangle (obtained via distance formula) are all equal to each other, then the rectangle is a square.